# camel-netty4: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty, activemq-artemis, netty4

I've looked through all the previous times some version of this question has been asked.
Here's an overview of the answers.

Unanswered:

- [How to find a root cause of the following netty error: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651707/how-to-find-a-root-cause-of-the-following-netty-error-io-netty-util-internal-ou)
- [Netty: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786464/netty-io-netty-util-internal-outofdirectmemoryerror)
- [I have enable the ResourceLeakDetector but I am getting OutOfDirectMemoryError instead of Netty memory leak error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838758/i-have-enable-the-resourceleakdetector-but-i-am-getting-outofdirectmemoryerror-i)

"Just up the memory":

- [reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InternalNettyException: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651791/reactor-netty-reactornettyinternalnettyexception-io-netty-util-internal-outofd)

"Set AUTO_READ to False":

- [Netty server memory usage keep increasing and eventually crashes with io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572490/netty-server-memory-usage-keep-increasing-and-eventually-crashes-with-io-netty-u)
- [Why Netty 4 "proxy" example has to set channel "AUTO_READ" as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273305/why-netty-4-proxy-example-has-to-set-channel-auto-read-as-false)
- [Netty ChannelRead method is not getting invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207914/netty-channelread-method-is-not-getting-invoked).

In my case, I'm inside Apache Karaf, and I'm already up to 2GB of Direct Memory, and I can't up it further. I pass the Camel context to my bean to get a Camel `producerTemplate`. Then I am just sending XML to a queue which goes to a bean. Netty isn't even used in this service, which is a bit odd. So it must be under the hood for ActiveMQ Artemis. I'm not sure where I would set the 'auto_read' to false, when I'm not configuring Netty myself, and Camel doesn't have settings for it.

```java
producerTemplate.sendBody(queueName, xStream.toXML(corMessage));
```

Here is my exception (after weeks of running fine):

```
io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 14379335 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 1895825408, max: 1908932608)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.incrementMemoryCounter(PlatformDependent.java:806)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:735)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:649)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newUnpooledChunk(PoolArena.java:638)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateHuge(PoolArena.java:214)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:141)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:126)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:396)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnection.createTransportBuffer(NettyConnection.java:253)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.protocol.AbstractRemotingConnection.createTransportBuffer(AbstractRemotingConnection.java:189)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketImpl.createPacket(PacketImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketImpl.encode(PacketImpl.java:322)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:475)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:434)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.sendFullMessage(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:552)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.sendRegularMessage(ClientProducerImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.doSend(ClientProducerImpl.java:268)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.doSendx(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:483)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:220)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:95)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:634)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSend(JmsConfiguration.java:647)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSendToDestination(JmsConfiguration.java:586)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.access$100(JmsConfiguration.java:528)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate$1.doInJms(JmsConfiguration.java:542)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:539)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:440)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:394)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:528)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:493)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:369)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:493)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:229)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:161)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:168)
```

Anyone able to help me debug this?

Comment: What version of the ActiveMQ Artemis core JMS client are you using?

Comment: artemis-jms-client is artemis-2.16.0.redhat-00046, netty-core is 4.1.66.Final-redhat-00001

Comment: Have you tried with a newer version of ActiveMQ Artemis? Version 2.16.0 was release almost 3 years ago now. There been something like 20 more releases since then.

Comment: Thanks, in the context of running RH AMQ Broker (7.9) alongside RH Fuse ESB (7.11), I'm still on Java 8, and upgrading our entire codebase to Java 11 and JakartaEE will be quite a task.  I think 2.16 is the last Java 8 Artemis?  So, unfortunately probably stuck with 2.16 for now.  If I start upgrading our entire stack away from Karaf to Spring Boot or Quarkus, with Artemis as MQ, would you recommend full upgrade to Java 21?

Comment: It's hard for me to provide a solid recommendation given the information you've provided. I think the most I can say is that ActiveMQ Artemis should work no problem with Java 21.

Comment: You can get help directly from the vendor Red Hat as you use their commercial products.